# Real time plotting with Matplotlib, PyQt and Threading ends to python crash

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, pyqt, queue

I've been struggling with my Python application and I can't find any answers.

I'm having PyQT GUI application which uses Matplotlib widget. GUI starts a new thread which handles plotting to mpl widget. I'm afraid I run now to a race condition by accessing matplotlib drawing components from another thread which leads to crash.

This is basically, what my code looks like:

```
class Analyzer(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    self.timer = QTimer()
    super(Analyzer, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.background = self.mpl.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.mpl.canvas.ax.bbox)

    self.plotQueue = Queue.Queue()
    self.plotterStarted = False

    self.plotter = Plotter(self.mpl, self.plotQueue)
    self.cam = Cam(self.plotQueue, self.textEdit)
    ...

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    ...
    self.mpl = MplWidget(self.centralWidget)
    ...

class MplWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
"""Widget defined in Qt Designer"""
  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.canvas = MplCanvas()
    ...

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
"""Class to represent the FigureCanvas widget"""
  def __init__(self):        
    # setup Matplotlib Figure and Axis
    self.fig = Figure()
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

    # initialization of the canvas
    FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)

    FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
```

And plotter class:

```
class Plotter():
  def __init__(self, mpl="", plotQueue=""):
    self.mpl = mpl
    self.background = self.mpl.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.mpl.canvas.ax.bbox)
    self.plotQueue = plotQueue
    ...
  def start(self):
    threading.Thread(target=self.run).start()

  ''' Real time plotting '''
  def run(self):
    while True:
      try:
        inputData = self.plotQueue.get(timeout=1)

        # Go through samples
        for samples in inputData:
            self.line, = self.mpl.canvas.ax.plot(x, y, animated=True, label='Jee')

            for sample in samples:
                x.append(sample['tick'])
                y.append(sample['linear'])

            self.line.set_data(x,y)
            self.mpl.canvas.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
            self.mpl.canvas.blit(self.mpl.canvas.ax.bbox)
         ...
```

So I pass mpl and plotQueue to Plotter class object. PlotQueue is populated in Cam class which processes incoming data from external hw. Plotter reads the plotQueue, processes it and calls drawing for mpl.

But is this a thread safe method to access mpl? If not, how should I do it? Any tips on this are appreciated.

---

Edit 1.

I added QTimer in main thread to handle drawing, as suggested in comments. After a small tweaking, I got it working fairly well.

```
class Analyzer(...):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QObject.connect(self.timer, SIGNAL("timeout()"), self.periodicCall)

  def periodicCall(self):
    self.plotter.draw()

  def startButton(self):
    self.timer.start(10)
```

Thanks a lot for useful comments.

Comment: I remember reading something about matplotlib having issues with threading.  _most_ plotting commands should be pretty fast (and you can use blitting to get around most slow cases), do them in your main thread.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been thinking too, but in this case my main thread is in Analyzer class which implements GUI. Analyzer class has buttons etc. so if I make there a loop which reads queue and calls plotting, it blocks the whole application.  

How am I able to do a loop in main thread?  

I believe it must be another thread doing the plotting, but how to do it thread safe? I could use synchronising, but in addition to my plot method, where should I put the other synchronised call, it should be somewhere inside matplotlib libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If matplotlib in your program is using the QT backend (which I assume it is since you are embedding it in a Qt application), then the drawing is going to be done in thread you call the matplotlib commands from. This is going to be a problem because Qt requires that all drawing is done from the main thread. **So I'm fairly certain you can't fix it simply.** (if you were using GTK you could use the gtk lock to prevent the main process from interacting with the GUI while you did GUI related things from your thread, but Qt got rid of their similar lock in v4 and above).

You have a few options:

1. Try and separate out the drawing parts of matplotlib (may not even be possible?) and have them run in the main thread by sending events with `QApplication.postEvent()`
2. Instead of using a thread, just use callbacks in the main thread (maybe called periodically using a QTimer or when the program is idle). This probbaly won't impact the performance of your application since the Python GIL prevents true multi-threading behaviour anyway.
3. Use a different plotting library. I had a look over [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/) the other day, and it seems to be coming along nicely. From my brief glance I think it has the ability to handle all of this behind the scenes for you, using a `RemoteGraphicsView`. This would launch a second process for doing the CPU intensive plotting stuff, which gets around the aforementioned Python GIL issue. Check out the examples they provide if you are interested

Comment: Thank you very much.   
The option 1. is something I tried to figure out in previous post comment, but I believe that's not the way to go.  
  
The option 2. could work for me. And I will check the option 3. as well, if the library offers me what I need.

Comment: Or what if I have a callback method in main thread which does plotting. And I call this method from thread passing it required arguments. So basically, I just have thread instead of timer calling the method?

Comment: That won't work because the method you call will be executed in the thread, not the main thread. You need to make the function run in the main thread by using QApplication.postEvent()

This is actually quite complicated, I'll try and get some code up for you in the next 24 hours (just have to check with the person who wrote it that he is happy to release it)

Comment: No, that's not necessary. I will go with timer as it actually seems quite valid method for doing things like these. Drawing is not as critical process as processing data which is done in other threads.

Comment: I added timer, but plotting seems quite laggy and doesn't look nice. I don't know why. I tried very short delays for timer, but even then. With threaded model (which crashes occasionally), plotting is very smooth.

Comment: Try setting the timeout of the QTimer to 0. This will have the callback run when the GUI thread is idle. You might also want to modify your code so that it:
A) Doesn't block trying to get something from the queue (given you have timeout=1 I assume it blocks for 1s if nothing is in the queue)
B) Get's everything it can out of the queue, rather than just one item each time

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out myself too. The queue timeout blocks, though it shouldn't matter, as if there's no data, then we just wait it. So, actually timeout is faster than just looping it again and again, until data is available. If queue doesn't get data, then the issue is in the other end of the queue. Yes, I read all the data from queue.